# Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly does not work in PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm migrating my application from PyQt5 to PySide2 and I came across this weird behaviour in PySide2.

I managed to reduce the code to this example:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
# from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget2 = QWidget(self)
        widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        widget3 = QLabel( "SomeLabel", widget2)
        widget3.setObjectName("widget3")

        for w in self.findChildren(QWidget, options=Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly):
            print(w.objectName())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = widget1()
```

Here I create w widget tree that looks like this:

```
widget1
  |_ widget2
     |_ widget3
```

Here PyQt5 prints `widget2` while PySide2 prints `widget2` and `widget3`. So PySide is doing a recursive search still. How do I work around this?

Comment: For me (using PySide-5.15.9), your script raises an exception, since the keyword `options` is not supported. This is in accord with the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.findChildren), which show there's no overload of `findChildren()` with that argument. I suppose one work-around would be to iterate over `children()` and filter with `isinstance()`; and another would be to swicth to PySide6 (which does support the `options` argument).

Comment: PS: see the existing issue on the qt bug tracker: [PYSIDE-905](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-905). Needless to say, this won't ever be fixed now in PySide2...

Comment: I think a switch to pyqt6 should be painless, if this is essential. Be aware, in PyQt6 the line would have to look a bit different: `for w in self.findChildren(QWidget, options=Qt.FindChildOption.FindDirectChildrenOnly):`

Comment: @Ovski If the code was written for Qt5 with original PyQt conventional naming and used lots of Qt flags, switching to PyQt6 is certainly far from painless. It's actually a migration from PyQt to PITA... ;-)

Comment: @musicamante understood. Honestly I just repeated what I was told myself, but never tried out. :) Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @Ovski You're welcome. Just remember that, while what we are told may be said from experienced people, that doesn't always mean that it's always correct and should always be assumed as absolutely valid: while experience usually results in wisdom, that doesn't mean that experience is always right; even experienced people may be wrong (experience can be a bias) or they don't fully understand *your* case or experience into account. Always try to put in doubt what you know or what you've been told: be ready to confirm as much as to invalidate your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in PySide, which was fixed in version 6.1. Sadly, most bug fixes are done on PySide6(6.x) and not backported to PySide2(5.x). See [PYSIDE-905](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-905) for details.

So if you really want that feature, either use PySide6 or PyQt5.

If you don't mind hacking PySide2, you can do a monkey-patching on the `QObject` like the following. (It's basically the same idea as the one in the musicamante's answer, but I think this one is more rigid.)

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QRegExp, QRegularExpression

old_findChildren = QObject.findChildren
def new_findChildren(self, type, name=None, options=Qt.FindChildrenRecursively):
    if options & Qt.FindChildrenRecursively:
        return old_findChildren.__get__(self)(type, name)
    if name is None:
        match = None
    elif isinstance(name, str):
        match = lambda child: child.objectName() == name
    elif isinstance(name, QRegExp):
        match = lambda child: name.indexIn(child.objectName()) != -1
    elif isinstance(name, QRegularExpression):
        match = lambda child: name.match(child.objectName()).hasMatch()
    else:
        raise TypeError('type must be None, str, QRegExp, or QRegularExpression')
    return [child for child in self.children()
        if isinstance(child, type) and (match is None or match(child))]
QObject.findChildren = new_findChildren
```

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about regex, good catch! Just some notes: 1. we should always avoid protected keywords such as `type` (I know that it's a "close" work around and that shouldn't interfere, but, still, it's for learning purposes and we should not suggest wrong names); 2. why the `__get__` usage?; 3. I also thought about using lambdas, but, at that point, wouldn't it be better to create "_private" global functions instead? In the end, there's no need for a context as a lambda would require: in fact, we could just reference the function and always provide both child and name arguments.

Comment: For the ```type```, I did that because ```help(QObject.findChildren)``` for PyQt5 showed ```findChildren(self, type, ...)```. (Sometimes it's very tempting to use ```type``` as a variable name.) For the ```__get__()```, you need to use it to get a bound method in general. (Think about a method using the ```super()```.) For using the lambdas, it's more simple and faster than using global functions because it uses less arguments.

Comment: Yes, you're right, even PyQt uses `type`. But I don't really agree with it (even if it's compliant to the C++ API): as you know, `type` is a builtin, C++ can use it because it doesn't have such keyword, but since that function is closely related to *types*, it creates a conceptual issue (it's trivial, I know, but it's important to consider it). About the `__get__`, I'm not sure I'm following (but I actually rarely used `__get__` explicitly): shouldn't it be the same as `old_findChildren(self, type, name)`? AFAIK, at least in this situation, there should be no difference (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Then, while I agree with your reasoning behind having less arguments in the lambda, I'm also considering the general purpose (and possible performance requirements) of such functions: the difference in code writing/readability is just a *single* further argument, which is quite negligible if compared to the constant creation (and further destruction) of a lambda in a function that could potentially be used very frequently, requiring as little time as possible to return (which is the reason behind using comprehensions in my answer). One of the main purposes of functions is their reusability.

Answer (score 1):

Since the requirement is for PySide2 (aka, Qt5) and it's unlikely that any PySide6 fix will be backported, you can still work around that with a simple helper function:

```py
def findChildren(obj, cls, name='', options=Qt.FindChildrenRecursively):
    if options == Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly:
        if not name:
            return [c for c in obj.children() if isinstance(c, cls)]
        return [c for c in obj.children()
            if isinstance(c, cls) and c.objectName() == name]
        
    return obj.findChildren(obj, cls, name)

directChildren = findChildren(someWidget, QWidget, options=Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly)
```

<sup>Note: while complex comprehensions are normally discouraged and normal `for` loops are preferred, I used them for optimization purposes; this is supposed to be a workaround that should work as fast as possible, similarly to the original Qt function, and while the performance difference with the creation of a local list along with an explicit for loop might be negligible, the succinctness and shortness of a comprehension for this purpose is justified, in my opinion.

Also, this solution just uses string based object names for the first argument, if you want to use regular expressions, see the more strict but also more compliant code in the [answer provided by relent95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76168902/2001654).</sup>

You can even "override" the basic `findChildren` function with a little and hacky monkey patch at the class level: you need to create another reference to the class function (so that you can call it when using the default recursive search), and then overwrite the function name with the custom function:

```py
def _findChildren(obj, cls, name='', options=Qt.FindChildrenRecursively):
    if options == Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly:
        if not name:
            return [c for c in obj.children() if isinstance(c, cls)]
        return [c for c in obj.children() 
            if isinstance(c, cls) and c.objectName() == name]
        
    return obj._findChildren(obj, cls, name)

QObject._findChildren = QObject.findChildren
QObject.findChildren = _findChildren

directChildren = someWidget.findChildren(QWidget, options=Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly)
```

Be aware that, in order to ensure that it works properly, you should do the above right after the *first* PySide import of your program.

Also, since we're overriding an existing function, you should ensure that the patch was not previously applied: in case you have a very big project, you may need to test small parts of your code that still require these fixes, but if you try to do the above multiple times, it can become ugly.

I normally create a "compatibility" script that groups all fixes and workarounds that are not available for a specific Qt version (major and minor) and just import it when required at the end of the normal imports. Most of the times, they are fixes that provide support for non existing functions (using `if hasattr()` to check if the function is available), but that can be done even in this case, since we know that we created an additional reference:

```py
if not hasattr(QObject, '_findChildren'):
    def _findChildren(obj, cls, name='', options=Qt.FindChildrenRecursively):
        ...
    return QObject._findChildren(obj, cls, name)

    QObject._findChildren = QObject.findChildren
    QObject.findChildren = _findChildren
```